# Does Django has an option to update one Boolean field in a model without much development?

Tags: django

So the question is more general.
I often have to update just one flag in my django apps . Usually a boolean flag for example you start working on some order and you set the flag to is_inprocess = True.

And there plenty of situation of this type. So each time I have to develope a form a view a template for each flag and I have a lot of those. Is there an easier way to do it with django? Just ticking some checkbox in my template. One fit all solution? (In my case I use Function based views)

Comment: Why don't you implement a dedicated API for that and then just submit an ajax request. No dedicated template, No dedicated form, Just a single `view` and `url` to render the request.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is the Django's orm `.update()` method 'much development'?

```
Model.objects.filter(pk=object_id).update(is_inprocess=True)
```

Comment: I still need separate view and URL to do it ?

Comment: It is not a problem if there is one but I have about 20 different flag updates in the process to be added so it will translate into 20 new view files

Comment: @BorisTheAnimal No, that's just a single line of code, you can execute it wherever you have the `object_id`

Comment: @BorisTheAnimal You can pass more than one field in the `update` method.

Comment: Ok, you mean click in template?User has to set up the flag

Comment: If you want to do it with _one click_ in template, you can implement AJAX, without any template.